# How to get a dictionary instead of a list from mongodb query?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary

This is what I am currently using

```
db.my_col.aggregate([
     '$match' :{'name':{'$in':['abcd','ecdf']}},
     '$project':{
          '_id':1
          'from':1,
          'to':1,
          'name':1
     }
     ])
```

I am using the result in python, which gives me cursor which I convert to a list, but I dont want a list I want a dictionary with the '_id' as the key and the other elements as the value

```
Expected Result:
{'_id': {'from':'value' , 'to':'value' ,'name':'value'}
```

And in another case I want to a dictionary grouped on from.

```
{'from' : [
          {'_id':'value','to:'value','name':'value'}
          {'_id':'value','to:'value','name':'value'}
'from2':[]
}
```

How can I achieve this, I am new to mongodb and confused on how to convert one of the values into a dictionary key.

Comment: Please provide sample o/p after `$project` stage also couple of original docs as well, that would be easy that way.. meanwhile you can try with `$group` stage, So when you `aggregate` or `.find()` what you get is a cursor(because it holds multiple documents) from mongoDB which you would convert to list/array in programming language for usage. Do you want that list to be a dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

aggregate query always return cursor and after converting you will always get list.